# Receiving Flutter ListView taps to prevent autoscrolling when user is scrolling. VerticalDragGestureRecognizer onEnd is not called on Android

Tags: flutter, gesture, flutter-listview

While streaming the text response from openai, I show this to the user. I want it to autoscroll down as the messages arrive. But not when the user is scrolling himself. How could I do that?

Simply wrapping the ListView in a GestureDetector does not work, the ListView consumes the tap events.

Copilot created this VerticalDragGestureRecognizer (which I do not understand), but it does successfully handle onDown and onCancel events. But the onCancel event is called immediately after onDown.

And onEnd is never called on Android.

Any idea's how I could fix this? Just stop autoscoll for the rest of the session in onDown?

The openAI streaming is not in the example, just a ListView with gesture detection.

Dardpad gist: https://dartpad.dev/?id=7446ee827ab50a9b7c69e997fd8660b7
For the web, it works, for android onEnd is never called.

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Map<Type, GestureRecognizerFactory> gestures =
      <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{};

  bool userHoldsScreen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    gestures[VerticalDragGestureRecognizer] =
        GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
      () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
      (VerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
        instance
          ..onDown = _handleDragDown
          ..onStart = _handleDragStart
          ..onUpdate = _handleDragUpdate
          ..onEnd = _handleDragEnd
          ..onCancel = _handleDragCancel;
      },
    );
  }

  void _handleDragDown(DragDownDetails details) {
    // Handle drag down

    userHoldsScreen = true;
    print("_handleDragDown, userHoldsScreen: $userHoldsScreen");
  }

  void _handleDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    // Handle drag start
    print("_handleDragStart, userHoldsScreen: $userHoldsScreen");
  }

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    // Handle drag update
    print("_handleDragUpdate, userHoldsScreen: $userHoldsScreen");
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    // Handle drag end
    userHoldsScreen = false;
    print("_handleDragEnd, userHoldsScreen: $userHoldsScreen");
  }

  void _handleDragCancel() {
    // Handle drag cancel

    print("_handleDragCancel, userHoldsScreen: $userHoldsScreen");
    //userHoldsScreen=false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Selective Drag Event firing',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: RawGestureDetector(
            gestures: gestures,
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            child: ListView(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  20,
                  (index) => Card(
                          child: SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Center(child: Text("Item $index")),
                        ),
                      ))),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```